# How to fix a data frame not showing up in a Shiny app

Tags: r

I'm attempting to create a simple data frame which is shown depending on my input (Checkbox), but it doesn't show in a [Shiny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shiny_(software)) app. It simply shows the inputs and no matter what I use, it stays completely blank.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput(
    inputId = 'CurrentVariable',
    label = 'Select Variable',
    choices = unique(c('artist', 'year')),
    selected = 'artist'
    )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$frametest <- renderTable({
    DataSet <- CurrentPlot[[input$CurrentVariable]]
    DataSet
    CurrentPlot
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The unchanged frame doesn't show either. How can I fix it?

I was expecting for it to at least show the original data frame without any changes, but that doesn't work either. I also tried using dplyr's Filter() function, but I couldn't manage to make it work.

Answer (score -1):

In your code, it seems like you are trying to access a data frame named `CurrentPlot` and select a column based on the checkbox input. However, I don't see any definition or assignment of `CurrentPlot` in your code, which might be causing the issue.

To resolve this, you need to have a valid data frame named `CurrentPlot` in your server function. Here's an example that demonstrates how you can modify your code to display a data frame based on the selected checkbox input:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput(
    inputId = 'CurrentVariable', 
    label = 'Select Variable',
    choices = unique(c('artist', 'year')),
    selected = 'artist'
  ),
  tableOutput('frametest')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Define a sample data frame
  CurrentPlot <- data.frame(
    artist = c('Artist 1', 'Artist 2', 'Artist 3'),
    year = c(2010, 2015, 2020)
  )
  
  output$frametest <- renderTable({
    # Filter the data frame based on the selected checkbox input
    DataSet <- CurrentPlot[, input$CurrentVariable, drop = FALSE]
    DataSet
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

In this example, I have created a sample data frame called `CurrentPlot` with columns "artist" and "year". When you run the app, it will display a checkbox input for selecting the variable. Once you select a variable, the corresponding column from the data frame will be displayed in a table.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot! The issue wasn't really the data frame itself, because I forgot to insert the other section of the markdown that would contain all that info (it was a csv file), but little details such as the "tableOutput" and using [, input...., drop..] seem to have done the trick! I still have to check everything, but for now it looks like you solved it, appreciated man!!

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).